# Super fast http requests while getting html doc

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, httprequest

this is my code: (I have changed it a little bit for understanding)

```
import urllib2

for number in range(0, 99999999):
    req = urllib2.Request('https://www.google.com')
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    print (response.read())
```

i use python 2.7 because it has urllib2 support (i have 3.6 too)
i have tried the "Requests" library (also tried http.client in python 3.6) and it works as urllib2's speed.

my aid is to get the html document from the URL fast as possible!
my code is works very slow (maybe my internet is little slow) my code make 1 request per 1 sec, not good , i need to make a 100 million requests and read their html.
i am just looking for something faster, thanks for advance.

Comment: In Python 3, [urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib2.html) has been split up into [urllib.request](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) and friends. There should be no reason to use Python 2 these days.

Comment: Take a look at [grequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests) (gevent + requests).  Forget about 100 million requests, you will probably get rate limited and/or your IP address blocked by a sysadmin before you get anywhere near that.

Comment: So, how many requests per second do you want to do? At what connection speed and latency and how much data per request?

Comment: right now 20mb/s and i will have 100mb/s soon.
and about the speed, i dont care if it will take a 24 hours to complete the task, right now it will take more than 2 months.

Let me worry about the ip block.. right now this is my priority :)